# turtle.onclick() doesn't work as supposed to

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have a script for a simple turtle race and I want the race to start when the user clicks the left-mouse-button so i have this code

```
def tur_race():
    for step in range(0, 135):
        tur1.forward(randint(1, 5))
        tur2.forward(randint(1, 5))


turtle.pu()
turtle.goto(-250, -150)
turtle.write("click the mouse to start")
turtle.ht()
turtle.onscreenclick(tur_race())
turtle.mainloop()
```

Assume that I have all variables defined.

when I run this code the race starts automatically and doesn't wait for the click.

Comment: `turtle.onscreenclick( tur_race )` without `()` after `tur_race`

Comment: @furas you could have added this as an answer. Couldn't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onscreenclick` takes a function as its parameter. You shouldn't be calling `tur_race`, turtle will do that when there is a click, rather you should pass `tur_race` itself. This is called a callback, you provide a function or method to be called by some event listener(e.g. the mouse being clicked on the screen).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @nglazerdev excellent answer, this would be your code after you apply what he said.

```py
from turtle import *
def tur_race():
    for step in range(0, 135):
        tur1.forward(randint(1, 5))
        tur2.forward(randint(1, 5))


turtle.pu()
turtle.goto(-250, -150)
turtle.write("click the mouse to start")
turtle.ht()
turtle.onscreenclick(tur_race)
turtle.mainloop()
```

You take out the `()` in the `tur_race` function. Otherwise, it will be called immediately.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

You need `turtle.onscreenclick( tur_race )` without `()` after `tur_race`

---

Python can assign function's name (without `()` and arguments) to variable and use it later - like in example

```
show = print
show("Hello World")
```

It can also use function's name as parameter in other function and this function will use it later.

Offen (in different programming languages) this funcion's name is called `"callback"`

In `turtle.onscreenclick( tur_race )` you send name to function `onscreenclick` and `turtle` will use this function later - when you click screen.

---

If you use `()` in `turtle.onscreenclick( tur_race() )` then you have situation

```
result = tur_race()
turtle.onscreenclick( result )
```

which doesn't work in you code but can be useful in another situations.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to everyone's answer, you need to add x and y parameters in the tur_race function. This is because turtle passes x and y parameters to the function, so your code would look like:

```py
from turtle import *
def tur_race(x, y):
    for step in range(0, 135):
        tur1.forward(randint(1, 5))
        tur2.forward(randint(1, 5))


turtle.pu()
turtle.goto(-250, -150)
turtle.write("click the mouse to start")
turtle.ht()
turtle.onscreenclick(tur_race)

turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
    from turtle import *
    def tur_race():
        for step in range(0, 135):
            tur1.forward(randint(1, 5))
            tur2.forward(randint(1, 5))
    
    
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.goto(-250, -150)
    turtle.write("click the mouse to start")
    turtle.ht()
    turtle.Screen().onclick(tur_race)
    
    turtle.mainloop()
```